# Copying text in Chromium and pasting it into gnumeric does not work

Tags: chromium, clipboard

When I copy text in Chromium, I cannot paste it into gnumeric; simply, nothing happens when attempting to paste.
I can however paste the text into gvim.
So to copy some numbers from Chromium into gnumeric, I have to first paste into gvim, then select and copy again in gvim, and then I can successfully paste into gnumeric.

--
Gvim 9.0.1189
Gnumeric 1.12.55
Chromium Version 116.0.5845.110 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)
Ubuntu 23.04 lunar
Xfce Version 4.18
GTK Version 3.24.37